# Need to deny all IPs except mine from accessing site and display friendly error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ip-address

I need to deny all IPs except mine.

I got my outward facing IP from whatismyip.com. Let's assume it is 200.200.200.200

Here is the beginning of my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403 /down.html

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 200.200.200.200
</Limit>
```

This works with the denying part - it shows my down.html page. However it denies me even when I place my correct IP in the .htaccess. Am I doing something wrong?

Also the down.html page contains an image - but seeing as all requests are being denied, I had to host it on a different domain to get it to display. My .htaccess skills are a little rusty, but how would I go about allowing that one image request through using .htaccess on this domain?

Comment: Regarding close... I thought these sort of questions were valid on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Web **server** config -> serverfault

Comment: Hmm.. can a mod auto shift it over, should I wait for close votes or should I reask there and delete here?

Comment: @alex: don't worry about it. if there's enough cranky people, they'll migrate it for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
allow from 200.200.200.200
deny from all
</Limit>
```

Comment: <Limit GET POST>, what about PUT and DELETE commands? Can we use Limit * ?